# What do if I add express and gsap not working?

Tags: mysql, node.js, gsap

If I type import express from 'express';
then gsap if not work

I dont know what is "expect"

Comment: Add your attempted code to the question so that others can help you better

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.